# Confused about use of "one another" in a possessive way

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence, I don't understand why there is a 's at the end of "one another":

> We are constantly making comparisons to one another's success.

Does this sentence make sense? If not please help me fix it. Thank you.

Comment: We're constantly comparing the degree of each other's success.

Answer (score -1):

"One another" typically holds the same meaning as "each other". It means "Every member in a group of two or more"

Comment: The question is about the possessive.

Comment: As I said, it has the same meaning as "each other".

Comment: That’s not the possessive.

Comment: The success belongs to one another